# Multiple types of Ok() in a Rust warp handler gives error

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-warp

I'm pretty new to Rust and I don't appear to understand why

This code example is a web handler using an external database with [warp](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/index.html):

```
use super::data;

use std::convert::Infallible;

pub async fn get_product(id: u32, repo: data::Repository) -> Result<impl warp::reply::Reply, Infallible> {
    let result = repo.get_product(id.to_string()).await;

    match result {
        Ok(product) => Ok(warp::reply::json(&product)),
        Err(e) => {
            // add proper logging here
            println!("Error on get {}", e);
            Ok(warp::reply::with_status(warp::reply(), warp::http::StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST))
        },
        
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the Result value is an `impl warp::reply::Reply`, so that any struct that has that trait can be returned. There are two `OK()` used here, in keeping with the Infallible error strategy. If there is an error, the handler should not throw any error, but just return a 400 error.

Both the structs returned--[warp::reply::Json](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/reply/struct.Json.html) and [warp::reply::WithStatus](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/reply/struct.WithStatus.html)-- implement the [warp::reply::Reply](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/reply/trait.Reply.html) trait. So, in my thinking from other languages, this should be good.

This is the error that I get:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/product.rs:13:16
   |
13 |             Ok(warp::reply::with_status(warp::reply(), warp::http::StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST))
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `warp::reply::Json`, found struct `WithStatus`
   | 
  ::: /home/usename/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/warp-0.3.1/src/reply.rs:72:19
   |
72 | pub fn reply() -> impl Reply {
   |                   ---------- the found opaque type
   |
   = note: expected struct `warp::reply::Json`
              found struct `WithStatus<impl Reply>`
```

Why can't I pass two different structs that meet the same trait in different Ok()'s?

Comment: Hello, in case of error Result expect an Err() not an Ok. In your case Err(Infallible), Err(warp::reply::with_status(warp::reply(), warp::http::StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST)))

Comment: Also note [this Reddit thread](https://old.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/gqq21b/return_multiple_reply_types_with_warp/) with code that is virtually identical to yours.

Comment: When a function return an impl, it means its the same as making it return a generic type. But that type has to be the same in the function because 2 different types can have different sizes for example. The reason to use impl in the return type is to let the compiler do the work and avoid writing the whole type.

I have never worked with warp, but here you may need to return an "Result<Box<dyn warp::reply::Reply>, Infallible>".